# ASP.Net - Json webmethod result in brower

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webmethod

I am trying to call a json webmethod (present in the code behind file) from browser. 
But get no output!

In my json.aspx.cs  page: the web method is

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class _default : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public string[] UserDetails()
            {
                return new string[] { "abc", "def" };
            }
        }
```

When I try the following url from browser:

http://www.mydomain/json.aspx/UserDetails

I get no result! (The page is blank) I expect - the browser to show - { "abc", "def" }

Correct me if I am doing something wrong. My intention is to get the result as plain text in browser. Is it not possible to achieve if I place the webmethod in the code behind? I don't want to create a separate service for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually none of the above worked.

Now instead of web form-code behind, I created a new asmx page & put it in the code behind
Now, it shown some config issues:
To solve it, I added:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

............

in thw eb config file.

Now I am getting the output in the browser.

The only thing remaining now - is I want it as plain text (json).

But I get it as xml:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<string>abc</string>
<string>def</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I am looking to fix this also.

Answer (score 1):

Is _default really the name of the class of is that just a mistake in the example? Should it not be json?

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Json : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a script manager on the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
// hook this up to a button click
function Test()
{
    PageMethods.UserDetails(Success);
}

// this is the callback from the page
function Success(Data)
{
    alert(Data);
}
```